# Controlling LED from web using ESP8266 NodeMCU devkit v3

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I want to control LED on web using ESP8266 NodeMCU devkit v3. I have followed [this tutorial](http://internetofthinking.blogspot.com.tr/2015/12/control-led-from-webserver-using.html). I have uploaded the code to the device, there is no problem until here. But when I open the Tools->Serial Monitor the result is not same the tutorial.The result is :
[image: result]

There is no problem in the WiFi connection. So anyone knows what is the problem?

Comment: That looks like early bootloader output, before your program would start. Maybe the flash didn't complete? You sometimes need to hold down a button

Comment: I hold down the button but result has not changed.

Comment: I removed the `nodemcu` tag but added `arduino` instead. Side note: there's no such thing as a true "NodeMCU V3 devkit". V3 is an invention by LoLin which is unrelated to NodeMCU, see http://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/ for details. I agree with Adam, looks like a flashing issue.

Comment: @MarcelStör I have tried to control led without wifi using blink example which is shown is the arduino ide. But I couldn't do it over wifi  and tried it ather esp module and it works good. I guess the problem is look like in the wifi module.